# How to fill a combobox with many values from different database?

Tags: lotus-notes, xpages, lotus-domino

I've tried with @DbColumn but I get Infinity, this is my current code:

```
var dbName:NotesDatabase = session.getDatabase("the server", "the database.nsf");
var v:NotesView = dbName.getView("the view").getColumnValues(0);
return v;
```

But this returns about a hundred results and after that I get distorted text, hieroglyphs, values in different lines etc.

A screenshot of the values:

[image: I've never seen anything like this before]

Now what? Thank you very much!

Comment: Now look into the view and see if this content is also shown in your view.

Comment: The same values are shown in the view of course, but not like hieroglyphs, they're shown perfectly fine...

Comment: Looks to me as a character encoding issue. Please take a look here http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: But all other values are perfectly fine

Comment: possibly < and/or > in column values scramble output html - try ctrl+f on view to look them up

Comment: Going back to what you said about @DbColumn, what do you mean by "I get infinity?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is something of a guess because I'm not an XPages guy, but it looks to me like you're saying:

```
var v:NotesView
```

And then

```
return v;
```

So this means you are declaring that v is a NotesView object.  You're actually assigning the columnValues, but the data type is wrong and there is apparently no type-checking going on.  So then you return v, and it is being treated as a NotesView object instead of as an array of string values.

Perhaps this is what you need:

```
var v:NotesView = dbName.getView("the view");
return v.getColumnValues(0);
```